# Is it possible to run member initializers before base-class constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization

Normally one can change the order in which member initializers run by changing the order in which the members are declared in the class. However, is there a way to get the base class initializer/constructor to not run first?

This is a minimal sketch of my problem:

```
class SpecialA : public A {
public:
    explicit SpecialA(Arg* arg)
        : member(expensiveFunction(arg))
        , A(member) // <-- This will run first but I don't want it to
    {}
private:
    T member;
}
```

Comment: Move those members into another class just for holding those members.  Then inherit from both the member holding class and the "base" class.

Comment: Why do you even need to do this? You could pass a `const T &arg`, like `SpecialA(expensiveFunction(some_value))` and avoid the whole problem.

Comment: @owacoder I need `Arg* arg` in the constructor for reasons that were stripped from the example, and restricting `expensiveFunction()` to this scope as an internal implementation detail simplifies the inter-class design.

Comment: @tennenrishin - Ah, I see. Well, it *is* a solution, albeit hackish. ;)

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not possible. Class initialization is always like that: base class, members, this class constructor.

The reason for this is simple - since you can reference your members in this class constructor, you have to construct members before you call your constructor. Since you can reference your base class members from your members, you have to have them constructed before this class members.

Answer (score 3):

Just realized how to solve the problem:

```
class SpecialA : public A {
public:
    explicit SpecialA(Arg* arg) : SpecialA(arg, expensiveFunction(arg)) {}
private:
    SpecialA(Arg* arg, T&& member) : A(member) , member(member) {};
    T member;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to run member initializers before base-class constructor?

Not as such.

That said, here are a few solutions:

1: move the member to an artificial base:

```
template<typename T>
class InitializerBase {
protected:
    InitializerBase(T&& value) : member(std::move(value)) {}

    T member;
};

class SpecialA: public InitializerBase<T>, public A {
public:
    SpecialA(Arg *arg) : InitializerBase<T>(expensiveFunction(arg)): A{}
    {
    }
};
```

(Probably) the best solution would look like this:

2: use dependency injection for the fully constructed value (this is safest, best design and unless your code has bigger problems, most efficient implementation):

```
class SpecialA : public A {
public:
    explicit SpecialA(T fully_computed_value)
        : A(fully_computed_value)
        , member(std::move(fully_computed_value)) // no heavy computations performed
    {}
private:
    T member;
}
```

Construction:

```
auto &a = SpecialA(expensiveFunction(arg));
```

This is the best solution because if `expensiveFunction` throws, you do not even start constructing the resulting object (the application doesn't have to release the resources for the half-constructed SpecialA).

**Edit**:That said, if you want to hide the use of the expensive function, the canonical solution to that (canonical because it is reusable, minimalistic and still respects good design) is to add a factory function:

```
SpecialA make_special(Arg *arg)
{
    auto result = expensiveFunction(arg);
    // extra steps for creation should go here (validation of the result for example)
    return SpecialA( std::move(result) );
}
```

client code:

```
auto specialA = make_special(arg); // simplistic to call (almost as simple
                                   // as calling the constructor directly);
                                   // hides the use of the expensive function
                                   // and provides max. reusability (if you
                                   // need to construct a SpecialA without
                                   // calling the expensive function, you 
                                   // can (by obtaining the constructor argument
                                   // for SpecialA in a different way)
```

Comment: I would choose the latter as well, but the OP mentioned they want the expensive function to be an internal implementation.

Comment: (In your first solution) you templated to avoid assumptions about some type, but then assumed the return type of `expensiveFunction`.  Since you are hard coding the name of `member`, you might as well hard code its type.  But maybe you shouldn't assume the type returned by `expensiveFunction`, so that should be templated for perfect forwarding.

Comment: I didn't consider those assumptions important; in fact, the code I wrote will not compile :); This is just a rough blueprint / pseudo-code, that is only precise enough to make my point (because that's how the code in the OP's question was written)

Answer (score 1):

Base class constructor must be called first.You cannot go any other way around but you can device a way to not make class A base class and call first whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The base class is always fully constructed first. There is no way round this.

One alternative would be to break the inheritance and move the the base class to a member variable of the child class.

The order of member initialisation is then the order they appear in the class declaration.

But relying on this can make your code brittle, so do bear that in mind. Putting a suitable comment in the class declaration might not sufficiently discourage an enthusiastic refactorer.

Answer (score 0):

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual
>   order of initialization is as follows:
>
> 1) If the constructor is for
>   the most-derived class, virtual base classes are initialized in the
>   order in which they appear in depth-first left-to-right traversal of
>   the base class declarations (left-to-right refers to the appearance in
>   base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>   left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the
>   constructor is executed

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

in your case it looks like it would be more correct to invert the ownership of the item:

```
struct A
{
protected:
  A(T expensive_object) : _expensive_object(std::move(expensive_object)) {}

protected:
  T& access_expensive_object() {
    return _expensive_object;
  }
private:
  T _expensive_object;
};

class SpecialA : public A {
public:
    explicit SpecialA(Arg* arg)
        : A(expensiveFunction(arg))
    {}

    void use_object() {
      auto& o = expensive_object();
      do_something_with(o);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a reserved optional parameter as a placeholder:

```
class SpecialA : public A {
public:
    SpecialA(Arg* arg, std::optional<T> reserved = {}) : 
        A(reserved = expensiveFunction(arg)),
        member(reserved)
    {}
private:
    T member;
}
```

It can be better than delegating constructors because it bloats code less when there is a lot of parameters. Also there may be more overhead with delegating constructors (please, correct me if I'm wrong).